# Referencing a WCF service method

Tags: c#, wcf

I had a service method in my WCF service and initially I was able to reference the method in my proxy class without any fails but later I changed my service method signature and updated the service reference(I am using Visual Studio 2010). But the problem is Service Client class is not updated with the latest service method and it still remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it works.

This is what I did, I restarted Visual Studio and removed the service reference from proxy and then added it back.

Answer (score 2):

What method are you using to update the service reference? Try right clicking on your service reference and selecting 'Configure Service Reference' then double check the service address is correct. Once that is done, click ok, then right click the service reference again and select 'update service reference'.

Comment: (I'm assuming you've got a http endpoint for your service) What do you get if you navigate to http://yoursite.com/ServiceName.svc?wsdl  The xml is not particularly easy to understand, but does it match the new method signature?

Comment: I can see the following and it is same for all other methods.

- <wsdl:operation name="MyMethod">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/MyService/MyMethod" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>

- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>